# Confirm from model in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

let us imagine that I have something like the following core/model:

```
class Core: ObservableObject {
  ...
  func action(confirm: () -> Bool) {
    if state == .needsConfirmation, !confirm() {
      return
    }
    changeState()
  }
  ...
}
```

and then I use this core object in a SwiftUI view.

```
struct ListView: View {
  ...
  var body: some View {
    List(objects) {
      Text($0)
      .onTapGesture {
        core.action {
          // present an alert to the user and return if the user confirms or not
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So boiling it down, I wonder how to work with handlers there need an input from the user, and I cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: so your question is how to present an alert?

Comment: not only, I know how to present an alert. But in the action handler, in `ListView` I need to present an alert and if the user presses "okay" return true or else false

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you reversed interactivity concept, instead you need something like below (scratchy)

```
struct ListView: View {
  @State private var confirmAlert = false
  ...
  var body: some View {
    List(objects) {
      Text($0)
      .onTapGesture {
        if core.needsConfirmation {
          self.confirmAlert = true
        } else {
          self.core.action()   // << direct action
        }
      }
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $confirmAlert) {
         Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"), 
             primaryButton: .default(Text("Confirm")) {
                 self.core.needsConfirmation = false
                 self.core.action() // <<< confirmed action
             }, 
             secondaryButton: .cancel())
     }
  }
}

class Core: ObservableObject {
  var needsConfirmation = true
  ...
  func action() {
     // just act
  }
  ...
}
```

**Alternate:** with hidden condition checking in Core

```
struct ListView: View {
  @ObservedObject core: Core

  ...
  var body: some View {
    List(objects) {
      Text($0)
      .onTapGesture {
          self.core.action()   // << direct action
      }
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $core.needsConfirmation) {
         Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"), 
             primaryButton: .default(Text("Confirm")) {
                 self.core.action(state: .confirmed) // <<< confirmed action
             }, 
             secondaryButton: .cancel())
     }
  }
}

class Core: ObservableObject {
  @Published var needsConfirmation = false

  ...
  func action(state: State = .check) {
     if state == .check && self.state != .confirmed {
         self.needsConfirmation = true
         return;
     }
     self.state = state
     // just act
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey @Asperi, thanks for your response.
I was hoping not to end up in a situation like this, where self.core.action() needs to be called at two places, and it is also problematic because `core.needsConfirmation` actually is a network call.

I was hoping Combine perhaps had a solution for a problem like this?